# FLASK - Send custom HTML tag from FORM to backend

Tags: python, flask

I have some custom tags into some inputs :

```
<input autocomplete="off" required="" name="facturationInfo_invoiceNumber" id="invoiceNumber" type="text" class="form-control" onfocusout="ocrOnFly(true, this, true); removeRectangle()" onfocusin="ocrOnFly(false, this, true)" x1_original="" y1_original="" x2_original="" y2_original="" value="FR24333489" page="1" x1="593" y1="426" x2="673" y2="456">
```

I am wondering if I have any chance to get the `x1, y1, x2, y2` etc.. on the flask backend ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (Actually not a complete no, but simply no).

But if you make changes like,

```
<input autocomplete="off" 
       required="" 
       name="facturationInfo_invoiceNumber" 
       id="invoiceNumber" type="text" 
       class="form-control"
       onfocusout="ocrOnFly(true, this, true); removeRectangle()"
       onfocusin="ocrOnFly(false, this, true)" 
       value="FR24333489"> 

<input type="hidden" name="x1_original" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="x2_original" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="y1_original" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="y2_original" value="">
```

Then you can access x1_original, x2_original etc. from request object.